# c# How to login to Google Reader

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, google-reader

I'm looking for a code fragment that will show me how to get an SID for Google Reader in C#.  Anyone know of such a beast?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy. First you should perform a `GET` request to `https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin` page with your login and password (don't forget to url encode them). And then just parse response (there will be several parameters divided by a new line character `\n`) to get `SID`. Here is a simplest example (no error handling):

```
var url = string.Format("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?service=reader&Email={0}&Passwd={1}",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email),
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password)
);
var web = new WebClient();
web.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    var sid = e.Result.Split('\n')
        .First(s => s.StartsWith("SID="))
        .Substring(4);
};
web.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```

But you could make this code more elegant by using [AsyncCTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to deal with manual HTTP manipulations and cookies for this. A pretty decent explanation is available on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI). If you worked with HTTP requests in C#, it shouldn't be a problem to pick up the methods described there.

Comment: I'm familiar with this page.  I was sort of hoping there was a code fragment out there I could use.  I did some HTTP request stuff for Windows Mobile 6 so I know it a little.  I was hoping there was something nice for it under WP7 like they did with WebClient but alas...